# Jquery animated scroll to top stops button from having rollover states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

Please be gentle as I'm not a coder and very much a beginner. I've figured out how to make a button positioned at the bottom of a long page make the page scroll back to the top but in an animated way. Big wow I here you say but not easy for me.

My button is contained in a div and did have rollover states. At first it appears black and when rolled over it appeared orange. Since adding the animate to top functionality I've lost the rollover states?

Any body have any ideas on how to fix this little problem? It really is the last problem I need to overcome to be able to finish my site. Here's a link to the page:

http://www.infomaticfilms.com/jack/jrimg/g_and_d.htm

Any help would be very much appreciated as usual.

Jack

Comment: You should probably use CSS in this kind of situation instead of JavaScript.

Comment: What I would do is have the hover image and static image as one.  Use CSS to hold the image as a `background-image` and change the `background-position` on hover.  A good example of this is on our pagination image: http://www.titaniumwebdesigns.com/wp-content/themes/titanium/images/pagination.gif

Comment: @Titanium - An example based on your gif: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ET753/

Comment: @Derek - Many thanks! A perfect working example for you Jack.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you not using dreamweaver to create your page. the javascript MM code is not readable so it is har to help you solve your problem..

You have 2 alternative to change your images on hover.

1) CSS recommended by Derek and Titanium. 
2) Change your script to use jQuery to change the images on hover.

[jQuery toogle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

[jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

If you want your page  to loas faster use CSS.

I highly recommend that you learn pure xhtml and css insted of using editors like dreamweaver. 
The time you put in to fix the crapy code that DD creates, you can put on learning html/html5 and css insted and get much better results in the end.

Feel free to contact me if you need help with pure html & css

Comment: Thanks very much for your time and help but I got it working. Don't know why but I just deleted the rollover images and then re-inserted them and bingo, it's working. Thanks again. http://www.infomaticfilms.com/jack/jrimg/g_and_d.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a href="#top">
<img src="images/jr_img_projectPage_top_button.gif"
onmouseout="this.src='images/jr_img_projectPage_top_button.gif'" 
onmouseover="this.src='images/jr_img_projectPage_top_button_ro.gif'"></a>
```

Another way is by using CSS :

```
.top {
    clear: both;
    height: 57px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    width: 84px;
    background: url("images/jr_img_projectPage_top_button.gif");
}

.top:hover {
    background: url("images/jr_img_projectPage_top_button_ro.gif");
}
```

Comment: Hello, thankyou so much for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately I don't have the brain to remember all the syntax and thus will never be a coder. I'm a visual person and so I'm stuck with Dreamweaver but I'm learning all the time. I tried the CSS approach which I thought would work but didn't. It solved the rollover problem but it stopped the animated scroll. I stripped out the rollover and re-inserted it and it worked? Planets must have aligned or something but it's all good now. http://www.infomaticfilms.com/jack/jrimg/g_and_d.htm

Comment: @jackrutter - `:hover` should be after `.top`